# How to reset and clear all previous Windows Index config?

Tags: windows-11, search-indexing

On Windows 11, when trying to add a drive, it would automatically include a bunch of folders and add them as excluded folders.

[image]

You can see the *Documents* and *Source* folders excluded automatically, but the further i get into the tree the messier it gets and the more folders are automatically added to the exclusion list.

[image]

I've tried resetting the index and change the *Allow files in this folder to have contents indexed in additon to file properties* setting on the parent folder's properties and apply it to all sub-directories (which took ages), however when I open the index options and add the drive it still automatically adds the same list.

The problem is that the excluded folder lists above don't disclose the full path of the folders, apart from being a looong list.

[image]

I tried manually removing all files in the new Windows settings but that the problem still persists.

[image]

Furthermore, even after I bothered removing it all manually one by one, once I click "Rebuild" the files are added back.

[image]

I believe there's a setting hiding in those directories, in the registry or elsewhere making these folders special.
I want to find that setting and eradicate it completely starting the index from scratch and include ALL files in this drive to the index.